# Why am I getting No module named error while the module does exist

Tags: python, linux, terminal

I am getting a No module named `Fs_AutoComapre_master` error while this module does exist.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and I am running my Python code via the Terminal with the following command:

`sudo python3 Automation/Trigger_Automation.py`

this is the tree :
[image]

Here is how I call the module in my code:
[image]

Comment: Can you please show how you call the module in your code?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I have edited the question.

Comment: And is it in your python PATH? Oh, and please, don't use images but text if it can be avoided.

Comment: yes, this is my python path 
['/home/shai/Desktop/Automation-KPI-Cross/Fs_AutoComapre_master/linux', '/usr/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.6', '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/home/shai/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages', 'Fs_AutoComapre_master']

Comment: Try doing ```from ./Fs_AutoCompre_master.FsCompare import test_perclass```

Comment: that's a syntax error